# AutoIt not work click the button id

Tags: windows-10, autoit

How can any program button id?
I tried ControlClick.

```
ControlClick ( "", "", 1837642, "left" , 1 )
```

or

```
ControlClick ( "", "", "WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.33c0d9d", [WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.33c0d9d] , 1 )
```

or

```
ControlClick ( "", "", "WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.33c0d9d", "WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.33c0d9d" , 1 )
```

or

```
ControlClick ( "", "", "", "WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.33c0d9d" , 1 )
```

for some reason does not work.(win10)

please help me

Comment: solution:
 Local $hWnd = WinWait("[CLASS:WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.33c0d9d]","",1)
ControlClick ($hWnd, "", "[CLASSNN:WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.33c0d9d10]")


///////////////////////////////


; Wait 10 seconds for the Notepad window to appear.
    Local $hWnd = WinWait("[CLASS:Notepad]", "", 10)

    ; Send a mouse click to the edit control of Notepad using the handle returned by WinWait.
    ControlClick($hWnd, "", "Edit1")